# Private IP of client machine from website

Tags: asp.net

Dear All, how can I get the **private ip of client system from a website hosted on public ip** in **ASP.Net C#?** while i am checking **userhostname**, it's showing the global IP of the Internet connectivity which is the same for all the machines in the network. Please advice me.

Thanks in Advance

Anoop George Thomas

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address/1907204#1907204

Comment: @Muhammad: That will work if the clients are coming through a proxy that adds the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR field, but there's generally no guarantee.  If it's coming through NAT and not a proxy, chances of that field are slim.

Comment: But Akhtar, I m getting reply "unknown" from the code

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no, not from the server side.  You may be able to write client-side code that looks up the system's actual IP address, though you may need to do it by way of a browser plugin.

A better question is "Why do you need do to that?"  Generally, if you have to have the internal IP, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Justin, I m using the code to restrict an online voting to be done only once from a particular machine.Is there any alternative?

Comment: There's no silver bullet, since the client can easily spoof HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.  The "right" solution is to require user accounts and only allow each account to vote once.  Otherwise you can use a combination of cookies, IP address, and the user agent (in its entirety) to thwart amateur attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not something you'll be able to pull.

Now, you can grab an IP of a machine that's coming through a proxy or other some such forwarding device.  Here's an example function that utilizes the HTTP_CLIENT_IP and the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR IP if they are available in your server environment.

```
<?php

function getIP(){
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}


echo getIP();

?>
```

Comment: He's looking for the solution on ASP.Net , Not PHP.