# ip address of request from httpheader

Tags: c#, http-headers, ip-address

I am trying to get the IP address of the request coming in from the httpheader. If value is x do something, if not do somthing else. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible Dupe of [#1907195](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). The HTTP standards do not define the source address as part of the protocol. Infact HTTP does not directly relate to IPv4 /IPv6 at all.

Generally, a webserver will easily be able to tell the network address of the other end of the socket ( the end where the web browser is ). It does not use HTTP to do this, rather it will use features of the OS's networking stack.

In the case of ASP.NET you should be able to find the IP address where the request came from. You might try looking at [System.Web.HttpRequest.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

Does [this](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB32_How-do-I-get-the-visitors-IP-address.html) help?  it seems pretty straight forward.

From the link, there are a few different ways:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;`

`HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];`

`HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];`