# How to retrieve my public IP Address using C#.Net? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-ip-address

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to get my own IP address in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)
>   [How to Get IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address)

I want to store the IP Address to the DataBase table through C#.Net coding. How to get the static IP Address(What we get from www.whatismyip.com) using C#.Net? What are the ways to retrieve it?

Comment: @Jalal: I edited my Question. Have a look at it.

Comment: @thevan; Get code from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address/1907204#1907204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it through `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName`

Comment: that gets the DNS name of the remote client, you use Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] to get the ip address of the client

Comment: are you sure? because, I have above code in my web application and it works ok.

Comment: @nevayeshirazi: Hi. I edited my question please look at it.

Comment: @thevan :my code should work fine. Do you work on your local machine or have you deployed your application to host or server ?

Comment: Yes. I worked it on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this:

HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

Comment: Hi. I edited my question please look at it.