# To get visitors IP address

Tags: .net

I would like to get the visitor's ip address.

Which one is the appropriate one to use:

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

or

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Which one is the best method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get IP Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address)

Comment: @AlastairPitts - No its not The question here is that which one of them to use ? And not how to Get Ip Adress .

Answer (score 1):

They're exactly the same. `UserHostAddress` simply calls `GetRemoteAddress`.

```
public string UserHostAddress
{
    get
    {
        if (this._wr != null)
        {
            return this._wr.GetRemoteAddress();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public override string GetRemoteAddress()
{
    return this.GetServerVariable("REMOTE_ADDR");
}
```

Both are also supported from .NET Framework 1.0/1.1 onward.

Answer (score 0):

both will return the same value as an IP-Address
i would prefer Request.UserHostAddress because it's definitely supported from .net framework 1.0 to 4.5

take a look:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Try using

`phpinfo();`

It should give you something like REMOTE_ADDR which is the variable you need to grab in your php script. This should be passed from the webserver to your PHP script.

Then use:

```
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

Comment: that'd be fine *if* using PHP, note it's using .NET in the tag (and Code)

Comment: Daniel - Before answering a question check the related tags, or the code mentioned in the question , then answer.