# Get user IP Address

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address

I have a web application that has a login. Now what I want is to get the IP address of that end user upon login. I've tried researching but based on what I understood, it gets the ip of my machine not the person that logins. This app is already deployed on a server. And if I do what they said, I will be getting the server's ip address. But I want the IP address of the end user that logs in.

This is a sample of what I've seen.

```
private string GetIP()
{
    string strHostName = "";
    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

    IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

    string ipaddress =convert.tostring(ipEntry.AddressList[2]);

    return ipaddress.tostring();

}
```

I'm not sure if I understood this correctly but I think this will get local ip address, not the ip address of the end user that is logging in. Please do correct me if I'm wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Public Ip address of a user in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 9):

Use -

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Answer (score 3):

Try both :

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use REMOTE_ADDR and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR from Request.ServerVariables .

The UserHostAddress property is simply a wrapper around the REMOTE_ADDR server variable. So if you user is behind a proxy (or router), this returns only one IP Address, the IP Address of the proxy (or router) .

Red : http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/11/A_Gotcha_Identifying_the_Users_IP_Address.aspx/

There is another thread in stackoverflow : [How to Get IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address/13249280#13249280)