# Is it possible to know ip address of user when user is communicating with bot?

Tags: botframework

I have developed a bot using directline api. If i want to know ip address of user when user communicate with bot first time,Is it possible to achieve?
If possible,How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways people say you should be able to get the ip of a user in asp.net but in my experience none of them work for the botframework.
([Here is something I have tried before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address))

If you are using the DirectLine api I am assuming that you built your own application to connect with the bot. You could try to get the ip inside the application and then send them to your bot by adding it to the header of the request or by sending a hidden message to your bot (a message on which the bot will not respond).