# Client IP using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

How can i get IP address of client machine in C#.?
I want to keep a log register for my online application and to keep IP address of logging system i want to get the IP address of client....

Advance Thanks...

Comment: How is the client connecting? What is hosting the server? ASP.NET? WCF? Sometime else?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

This doesn't attempt to take into account proxies.  For that, you can use `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`.  However, make sure you're not trusting that blindly, since it could be forged.  It's better to keep a whitelist of IPs for which you trust it.

Comment: It wont work. It returns 127.0.0.1 .My systen is in a network. I want the actual IP address of Client system

Comment: @Nithesh, it's working.  That *is* the IP that actually connected to the server.  This means your server is on `localhost`

Answer (score 8):

```
    String clientIP = 
(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]==null)?
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress:
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

Comment: As Wikipedia [notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For), the value of this header may be bogus.  Thus, it's safer to keep a whitelist of IPs for which you trust it.

Comment: String clientIP = 
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]??
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress is this not more readable? +1 one for proxy checking

Comment: Indeed it is more  readable, but I was not sure of .Net version OP is using.