# Asp.NET|Get Ip Of a user when he open the site\click on a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Simple as that.

i want to save the ip on a session id, or. when he click on a button it will do like that:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
          writer.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
          }
```

(its not all the code ofc)

when he click on a button, it will wirte the ip into the file. :)

any way to do so?

Comment: See if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Also, you might first want to check if he's behind a proxy:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"))) {
   string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
else {
   string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

}
```

And I would agree to @Barry's post about this not being a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user's IP address use `Request.UserHostAddress` although please note that this is not a perfect solution as it will not show individual user's where for example they are on corporate network behind a  firewall and only exposing one (or more) external company IPs.

Comment: i am have tryed do to this :protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Id"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress; 
    } , its not working when i am dogin :writer.WriteLine(Session["Id"].ToString());