# Get IP address of user computer in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)

I have a application in which i have to get IP address of user who accessing my site.
My site is hosted on Go Daddy hosting server.
I have tried several codes(which are listed below) but it seems they are not working.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString(); 

Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();

Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

HttpContext.Current.Request. Server Variables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

I have been working on this since last 3 days but i could not find any good solution.
Any good solution for this.

Please help me to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the output of those 5 ways you tried so far?

Comment: `string clientIPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;` is working for me.What do you get with this code?

Comment: Read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net

Comment: I have tried it out in aspx.cs page. it works in local intranet but when i upload it to Go daddy server it page does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [HttpRequest.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx)

Comment: Read the opening post. He/she tried out.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName).AddressList[0].ToString()
```

Comment: This gives host IP address. but i want to get IP address of user who is accessing my site.

Comment: I personally dont think its possible

Answer (score 0):

Those should work. Are you expecting to get the IP address of your computer **On your network**? (as opposed to the public one given by your ISP, that could change)

Comment: i supposed to get IP Address of client Pc who accessing my site.