# Get IP from computer name in intranet C# Windows application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get an IP address from computer name in same network...
Something like CMD command "nbtstat -a COMPNAME" in C# windows application

Comment: I tried all sort of things, but nothing worth mention

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get IP address of user computer in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737499/get-ip-address-of-user-computer-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Dns.GetHostAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx):

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("some pc name")
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()));
```

Comment: @Dudipoli probably you need to add `using System.Net;` to your using list

Comment: The problem was in one of the network card definition. Each time i tried to get his ip, i got no such host that's why i thought something was wrong with the code. Thanks

Comment: @Dudipoli Glad to know, this helped you

Answer (score -1):

Try this method:

```
Dns.GetHostName();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx

Comment: That gives me my computer name... I already have the computer name but now i'm trying to get his ip, from the computer name