# The difference among four ways to get the client ip address

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, .net-3.5, ip-address

Q:

I need to know the difference among the following:

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ;


Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

System.Net.IPAddress[] strClientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName);
```

I want to get the client `IP` address (the user who access the site)and I'm confused among the previous methods which one more accurate.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use the third option to get the client (or user) ip address.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

The first two methods also do the same thing.

But the last method do not return the client ip, it will return the server ip where your site is hosted. And for calling this method you must need to specify host name or ip address. However, `Environment.MachineName` returns the server name and therefore it will return server's ip not the user's ip.

For more information about your first two option I find the difference by googling, [here it is](http://www.powerasp.com/content/new/using-asp-to-retrieve-users-ip-address.asp)