# ASP.NET Web API: How do you read server variables in a Web API controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How would you read the following server variables in an ASP.NET **Web API** controller?

```
HTTP_HOST
SERVER_NAME
REMOTE_HOST / REMOTE_ADDR
```

I see a System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage Request defined, but I don't see a collection containing these variables.

I'm running a website on a single IP with multiple host headers and I need to determine which site they used to get there.

EDIT:

It ended up being something like this:

```
((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper) Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"])
    .Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
```

Comment: could this be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host

Comment: @MajorByte That is very similar yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The information you are looking for is dependent on the host you are using and Web API is designed to be host independent.  So.... the information you are looking for will be buried in the httpRequestMessage.Properties collection and it will be different depending on your host.

If you move to using the Owin adapter then you will get a standardized Owin environment object.

Comment: Good suggestions.  I can see `Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"].Request.Url` along with UrlReferrer.  Big question is whether it represents the host header of the site they visited.

Comment: I wonder if http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.aspx is a consistent way to read this information regardless of hosted environment?

Comment: ((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]

Comment: Dr. Zim, your comment deserves its own answer. I come back to this every once in a while and have to read the whole page before I find your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to all that information from the RequestUri within Request

```
  Request.RequestUri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + 
  Request.RequestUri.Host + (Request.RequestUri.IsDefaultPort ? string.Empty : (string.Concat(":", Request.RequestUri.Port)))
```

Comment: Well, this works only for the host uri. But not for anything else from server variables.