# ASP.NET Core 2 Equivalent of Request.Servervariables

Tags: asp.net, url, asp.net-core-2.0, request.servervariables

This is a little annoying thing.  Definitely not a show stopper.  What is the equivalent of `Request.ServerVariables`?
Specifically, I would like to know how I get the current URL?

I have previously done this by getting `Request.ServerVariables["script_name"]`.  I hate hard-coding text into a program, and I am finding that I would need to get the URL of the current page.  I'd like to get the current URL of the running razor page, but I can't figure out why.  Does anyone else know how to get the current URL in the current page?

Comment: Ever find anything out on this?  I'm having same problem accessing handful of different 'server variables' I used to use in asp.net.

Comment: Does this still work in core:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330758/asp-net-web-api-how-do-you-read-server-variables-in-a-web-api-controller