# How to give a time delay between two concurrent web requests in my web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API in which a controller is getting called repeatedly. I want to give a time delay between two web requests. Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Have you checked out this related SO question ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817300/how-to-throttle-requests-in-a-web-api (and especially the advice to use https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before hitting the controller, every request made hits the **ActionFilterAttribute**. You can create a class which is inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute.

```
 public class AuditTrails : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
          //Give the request a delay time here, For this you have to filter the request if it is hitting the same controller.
          //You can refer this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817300/how-to-throttle-requests-in-a-web-api
    }
  }
```

and then use [AuditTrails] at the class level of controller.

```
[AuditTrails]
public class Controller{}
```

If you are want to use thread-safety or you want to access a resource for a particular thread and lock it, then the best option is to use **lock** . For locking, you can refer this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement