# Limit number of requests from client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to return from a request if there's already a request in process from that client.

```cs
// Controller

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBarcode(string ticketId)
{
    var customerGuid = Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var ticketGuid = Guid.Parse(ticketId);

    return Json(await _service.GetBarcode(customerGuid, ticketGuid));
}

// Service

public async Task<TicketBarcode> GetBarcode(Guid customerId, Guid ticketId)
{

    // if already processing a request with this customerId and ticketId, then return

    // if not, then proceed
```

It calls another API which can't handle the pressure.

I'm asking for advice how to achieve this. If you need more info, please comment.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit

Comment: Thanks, but it's Core, this is Framework.

Comment: Yes, sorry, but if nothing else can be found you could grab the code and adopt it.

Comment: Did you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817300/how-to-throttle-requests-in-a-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly; you want something that prevent users to call your apis frequently. Well, there are multiple ways to achieve it.

You can use Radis; it provides [different patterns for Rate limiter](https://redis.io/commands/incr#pattern-rate-limiter), with use of that you'd able to configure rate limit e.g. maximum of ten requests per second per IP address.

Another straight forward way is to use nuget package of [`WebApiThrottle`](https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle#webapithrottle).