# C# - Throttle incoming API calls

Tags: c#, .net, api, throttling

Looking to restrict an API endpoint that I have to only so many calls per second. It doesn't matter who calls it, it just can't allow above a certain amount of (let's say 100) calls per second. What would be a good way of approaching this? And ideally if I can avoid using a NuGet package that would be great.

```
[HttpGet("myendpoint")]
public ActionResult<string> myEndpoint()
{
   // do work...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How would you handle requests above the limit? Queue them or error?

Comment: Take a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817300/how-to-throttle-requests-in-a-web-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to throttle requests in a Web Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817300/how-to-throttle-requests-in-a-web-api)

Comment: Something like this might help https://github.com/dotnet-labs/SemaphoreSlimThrottle

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Ideally it would be to queue them. But a returned error is an okay starting point as well.