# Asp Net Web API 2.1 get client IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Hello I need get client IP that request some method in web api,
I have tried to use this code from [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/05/retrieving-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-web-api/) but it always returns server local IP,
 how to get in correct way ?

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

from other questions:

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
    {
        private const string HttpContext = "MS_HttpContext";
        private const string RemoteEndpointMessage = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty";

        public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext))
            {
                dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
                if (ctx != null)
                {
                    return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
                }
            }

            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage))
            {
                dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
                if (remoteEndpoint != null)
                {
                    return remoteEndpoint.Address;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This extension method works well for me. (I'm not using OWIN or anything unusual.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the IP address of the remote host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Following link might help you. Here's code from the following link.

reference : [getting-the-client-ip-via-asp-net-web-api](http://www.herlitz.nu/2013/06/27/getting-the-client-ip-via-asp-net-web-api/)

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace Trikks.Controllers.Api
{
    public class IpController : ApiController
    {
          public string GetIp()
          {
                return GetClientIp();
          }

          private string GetClientIp(HttpRequestMessage request = null)
          {
                request = request ?? Request;

                if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
                {
                      return   ((HttpContextWrapper)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
                }
                else if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name))
                {
                     RemoteEndpointMessageProperty prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
                     return prop.Address;
                }
                else if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                {
                    return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
                }
                else
                {
                      return null;
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Another way of doing this is below.

reference: [how-to-access-the-client-s-ip-address](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig1/archive/2012/07/09/how-to-access-the-client-s-ip-address.aspx)

For web hosted version

```
string clientAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

For self hosted

```
object property;
        Request.Properties.TryGetValue(typeof(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty).FullName, out property);
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty remoteProperty = property as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
```

Answer (score 77):

With Web API 2.2: `Request.GetOwinContext().Request.RemoteIpAddress`

Comment: Note that this only works if you are using Owin - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.owinhttprequestmessageextensions.getowincontext(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 19):

Try to get the Ip using

```
ip = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress : "";
```

Comment: @DenisBabarykin I think it should,..it returns the IP address in the server variable REMOTE_ADDR

Answer (score 12):

Replying to this 4 year old post, because this seems overcomplicated to me, at least if you're hosting on IIS.

Here's how I solved it:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
...
[HttpPost]
[Route("ContactForm")]
public IHttpActionResult PostContactForm([FromBody] ContactForm contactForm)
    {
        var hostname = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(hostname);
        IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        ...
```

Unlike OP, this gives me the client IP and client hostname, not the server.  Perhaps they've fixed the bug since then?

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the most clear solution, using an extension method:

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
{
    private const string HttpContext = "MS_HttpContext";
    private const string RemoteEndpointMessage = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty";

    public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext))
        {
            dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
            if (ctx != null)
            {
                return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
            }
        }

        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage))
        {
            dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
            if (remoteEndpoint != null)
            {
                return remoteEndpoint.Address;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So just use it like:

```
var ipAddress = request.GetClientIpAddress();
```

We use this in our projects.

Source/Reference: [Retrieving the client’s IP address in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/05/retrieving-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 10):

If you're self-hosting with Asp.Net 2.1 using the OWIN Self-host NuGet package you can use the following code:

```
 private string getClientIp(HttpRequestMessage request = null)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_OwinContext"))
        {
            return ((OwinContext) request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"]).Request.RemoteIpAddress;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's better to cast it to `HttpContextBase`, this way you can mock and test it more easily

```
public string GetUserIp(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
    {
        var ctx = request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextBase;
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I googled around and others seem to concur with this (cast to HttpContextBase instead of HttpContextWrapper because HttpContextBase is easier to mock.)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similar to user1587439's answer, but works directly on the controller's instance (instead of accessing HttpContext.Current).

In the 'Watch' window, I saw that this.RequestContext.WebRequest contains the 'UserHostAddress' property, but since it relies on the WebHostHttpRequestContext type (which is internal to the 'System.Web.Http' assembly) - I wasn't able to access it directly, so I used reflection to directly access it:

`string hostAddress = ((System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper)this.RequestContext.GetType().Assembly.GetType("System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpRequestContext").GetProperty("WebRequest").GetMethod.Invoke(this.RequestContext, null)).UserHostAddress;`

I'm not saying it's the best solution. using reflection may cause issues in the future in case of framework upgrade (due to name changes), but for my needs it's perfect

Answer (score 2):

```
string userRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

This works on me.

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;` this one return me the same return I get from the `UserHostAddress`.