# How to get the IP address from ApiController?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How do I get the IP address of the client's IP address from inside an `ApiController`?

What is the equivalent of `Request.ServerVariables`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532806/asp-net-web-api-2-1-get-client-ip-address

Comment: Be aware that the "client's IP address" that you can pick up is just the IP address of whatever device is closest to you that may perform address translation - i.e. it could be your own organisation's NAT, the client's NAT, a proxy, etc.