# How to fetch server IP in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, server, asp.net-ajax

I have a **ASP.NET WEB API** Code that accepts few parameters.
Inside the WEB API code, I am using ***HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress*** to fetch the Request's IP Address;
I have another ASP.NET Website deployed on some other server **(Server = \x152)**, this website is having the **AJAX code** to call the Web API.
Now I am using my local machine to make a request to the website (on Server \x152) that in-turn can call the WEB API through the AJAX CAll written in the code.
**I want to get the IP address of Server \x152 in my WEB API code**, but everytime it is fetching the IP address of my local machine.
**How to fetch the IP address of the Server \x152?**

Comment: Hi Luvkush, I am also looking for same solution. Did you achieve this one. Please let me know, it will be very helpful for me. I have deployed my application in Azure APP service

Answer (score -1):

You may check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532806/asp-net-web-api-2-1-get-client-ip-address). It depends how is your application is hosted.

For web hosted version

```
    string clientAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

For self hosted

```
    object property;
    Request.Properties.TryGetValue(typeof(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty).FullName, out property);

    RemoteEndpointMessageProperty remoteProperty = property as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
```

Comment: string clientAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;  This code always giving the ISP IP address.