# Get ip access web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get an IP client in my AuthorizationFilterAttribute but only get the IP: 192.168.0.1. How to fix it?

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var ip = actionContext.Request.GetClientIpAddress();
    // Only get the IP: 192.168.0.1
}

public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext))
    {
        dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
    }
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage))
    {
        dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
        if (remoteEndpoint != null)
        {
            return remoteEndpoint.Address;
        }
    }
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(OwinContext))
    {
        dynamic ctx = request.Properties[OwinContext];
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            return ctx.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to test it from multiple clients? You always get the same IP?

Comment: What are the expected IP? Is 192.168.0.1 your IP? Your router's IP? Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22532924/3563910)?

Comment: yes, i have a host api, and i have used many hosts mvc call api in controller, but it get 192.168.0.1!

Comment: i want get ip wan client( host mvc) access to my api, i want  filter client to access it

Comment: I followed that post

Comment: Check for forwarded for header and work backwards to see if you get the desired ip

Comment: string clientAddress = "";             
clientAddress=HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
clientAddress=HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();

Comment: but i get 192.168.0.1

Comment: Then I suggest you use a sniffer and view the raw request to see if a header exists in the request that contains IP. that should allow you to know which header to look for