# How do I get client IP address in ASP.NET CORE 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

how to get a client IP address in ASP.NET 3.1 when writing code in Web API project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp Net Web API 2.1 get client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532806/asp-net-web-api-2-1-get-client-ip-address)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get client IP address in ASP.NET CORE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 11):

Use this tutorial. wish it will help you. 
[Get client IP address in Asp.NET core 3](http://bekenty.com/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core/)

Or just use this line of code in your controller:

```
var ip =HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()
```

Comment: The link is broken!

Answer (score 2):

```
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(); 

deviceName = Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).HostName;
```