# HTTPContext.Current.Request Ip address is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get IP address of client in asp.net Controller.

**I use this Code:**

```cs
string ip = string.Empty;
if (request.IsSecureConnection)
    ip = request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip))
{
    ip = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip))
    {
        ip = request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ip.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0)
        {
            ip = ip.Split(',').Last();
        }
    }
}
```

Sometime the `ip` is empty.
Do you have any idea why? Why is `ip` null in `Httpcontext.Current.Request`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp Net Web API 2.1 get client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532806/asp-net-web-api-2-1-get-client-ip-address)

Comment: I'm presuming this is Web api as *asp.net Controller* could be one of multiple technologies