# Asp.net Web Api 2 Get server ip address

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Web Api 2 and am trying to get the ip address of the hosting server so I can register google cloud messaging with that ip. I cannot seem to find a way to find the server host ip, only the requesting client ip. Is there a way to get my current ip of the server? Thanks

Comment: I think that you can find the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host