# How to get client IP address in Azure Functions C#?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm writing a function in C# using Azure Functions and need to get the ip address of the client that called the function, is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an answer based on the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host).

```
#r "System.Web"

using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string clientIP = ((HttpContextWrapper)req.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"The client IP is {clientIP}");
}
```

Comment: So this means one needs to shoehorn a System.Web.dll reference into the function somehow?

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson unfortunately I thin that's indeed the case. It's not Functions specific, as you'd have the same pattern in Web API (or anything that uses `HttpRequestMessage`).

Comment: I dont think this works any more, I get the same collection of IPS for all users, all within the 100* range. I've seen a post on MSDN where someone else confirms that things recently changed and he now gets the same even though MS_HttpContext worked before

Comment: @StevenElliott look at my updated answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46300183/4810304) AzureFunctions now behind a LoadBalancer

Answer (score 18):

you should use these function [Get the IP address of the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host)

request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] is not available if you debug precompiled functions local
request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] is not available on azure

```
private string GetClientIp(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
    {
        return ((HttpContextWrapper)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
    }

    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name))
    {
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty prop;
        prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
        return prop.Address;
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Update 21.08.2018:**
Now Azure Functions are behind a LoadBalancer --> we have to inspect Request-Headers to determine the correct Client IP

```
private static string GetIpFromRequestHeaders(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Forwarded-For", out values))
        {
            return values.FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ',' }).FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ':' }).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!
Was having a hard time with everyone saying "MS_HttpContext", yet it not being present in my function.

Comment: No longer works with .NET 7 with dotnet-isolation.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an extension method based on what I am seeing in

#### .Net Core 3.1

```
public static IPAddress GetClientIpn(this HttpRequest request)
{
    IPAddress result = null;
    if (request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-For", out StringValues values))
    {
        var ipn = values.FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ',' }).FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ':' }).FirstOrDefault();
        IPAddress.TryParse(ipn, out result);
    }
    if (result == null)
    {
        result = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### .NET 6.+

```
        public static IPAddress GetClientIpn(this HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            IPAddress result = null;
            if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Forwarded-For", out IEnumerable<string> values))
            {
                var ipn = values.FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ',' }).FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ':' }).FirstOrDefault();
                IPAddress.TryParse(ipn, out result);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Does not work in .NET 7 with dotnet-isolation.

Comment: While you're there, you can search the headers to determine if any comparable header is available.

Comment: @JussiPalo - it does for us... however it doesn't work for .NET 8 isolated worker. Perhaps some sort of config change required - would be good to know what this is if so!

Comment: @Kram as you can see by the code, this functions based on headers. The best recommendation that I can give you is to first write all of the header keys and values to a log file and see if what you need is already there. It may be named differently. If you find it, let's update the answer with a second if-statement to catch the header value that you find.

Comment: Yes I appreciate it's from the headers (in fact the ASP.NET Core integration uses this to set the RemoteIpAddress, which is why some people think that's the answwer). I am logging to file (and to screen via a debug function). Also I am using Static Web App with Azure Functions as API (Bring Your Own Functions) - and I am seeing sometimes it is correct: `x-forwarded-for: 82.1.123.8:62885, 13.69.116.3:65116` and sometimes it's incorrect `X-Forwarded-For: 13.69.116.3` - note that the correct one has the client IP first. The incorrect one only has Azure Data Centre IP first. Very odd indeed!

Comment: Also when I see the incorrect header, I also see that the `Host` is `locahost:port` whereas when I see the correct header, I see that the `Host` is the dns of the Azure functions app (i.e. `my-api.azurewebsites.net`) ... it feels like it's down to the way deployment and proxying is working somewhere deep inside Azure, and I don't seem to have able to control it.

Comment: @Kram it does sound like that may be the case. Since HTTP headers may have multiple values, are you certain that you wrote all of the values and not just the first value for each header? My thought is that perhaps there are 2 values, but that they aren't always written in the same order due to synchronous processes or some code that doesn't always execute in the same order.

Comment: @N-ate yes I am certain I write all values for the header - I also note that when it is "wrong" (i.e. in the case where Host = localhost), the header name is capitalised differently "X-Forwarded-For" instead of "x-forwarded-for" and the IP doesn't have the port. There definitely feels to be some sort of difference in deployment going on - I wonder if the load balancer sometimes has the Azure functions on the same VM as the Azure Static Web site and sometimes not - it does seem it's something like that but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 5):

Now that **Azure** functions get an **HttpRequest** parameter, and they're behind a load balancer, this function to get the IP address works for me:

```
private static string GetIpFromRequestHeaders(HttpRequest request)
{
      return (request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault() ?? "").Split(new char[] { ':' }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does work, but it returns the IP address of an internal box a 10.x.x.x address as of Decmeber 2021. Even using Azure Insights - their logs do not even provide the IP address of the clients.

Answer (score 5):

Update 18-Oct-2019:

The solution I tried is much easier and quicker and is mentioned below stepwise. But some more lengthy/tricky alternates are available @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection:

1. Login into Azure portal.
2. Open a new tab in same browser while you are logged in and dial “http://Resources.Azure.Com”
3. This is Azure back end services portal so being slightly careful in making changes would be great.
4. Expand SUBSCRIPTIONS section from the left panel and expand your Azure Subscription where app insight resource is located.
5. Expand Resource Groups section and expand the Resource Group where app insights resource is.
6. Expand the Providers section and find the Microsoft.Insights provider and expand it.
7. Expand the Components section and find and select your App Insight Instance by name.
8. On the right top change your mode to Read Write from Read Only.
9. Click EDIT button on the Rest API call.
10. ADD NEW “"DisableIpMasking": true property to properties section.
11. Press PUT button to apply changes.
12. Now your App Insight is enabled to start collecting Client IP addresses.
13. Do some queries on the Function.
14. Refresh and Test the App Insights data after about 5 to 10 minutes.

Comment: This combined with:
```csharp
IPAddress result = null;
                if (req.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-For", out StringValues values))
                {
                    var ipn = values.FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ',' }).FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ':' }).FirstOrDefault();
                    IPAddress.TryParse(ipn, out result);
                }
                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = req.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                }
                string IP = result?.ToString();
``` 
Worked

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already by others, the old method of looking at `MS_HttpContext` no longer works.  Further, while the method of looking at the headers for `X-Forwarded-For` does work, it only works after being published in Azure - it doesn't return a value when you're running locally.  That may matter if you prefer testing locally to minimize any potential cost-impact, but still want to be able to see that everything works correctly.

To see the IP address even when running locally, try this instead:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

And then:

```
String RemoteIP = ((DefaultHttpContext)req.Properties["HttpContext"])?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
```

This is working for me currently in Azure Functions V3.0.

Comment: 'HttpRequestMessage.Properties' is obsolete: 'Use Options instead.'

Answer (score -2):

In a .NET 6.0 function, within the `Run()` function of the operation, this can be accessed of the `HttpRequest req` object:

```
    public static class PingOperation
    {
        [FunctionName("ping")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            log.LogInformation($"PingOperation requested from: {req.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}:{req.HttpContext.Connection.RemotePort}");

            string responseMessage = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In an Azure production environment this returns the IP address of the Azure Data Center, not the client IP sadly....