# How to get client IP address in Azure Functions node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function written on node.js. How could I retrieved an IP address of a client that called the function?

What I've found so far:

1. An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582553/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-azure-functions-c) to the same question, but using C#.
2. It is possible to read it from headers:

   ```
   module.exports = function (context, req) {
       var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']    
   }
   ```

Is it reliable to get the ip this way, since it can be easily changed on the way to the function?

Comment: Yes it is reliable, because Azure web server will overwrite x-forwarded-for as it knows it is forwarding from load balancer.

Comment: Thank you Akash! Could you put this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is reliable, because Azure web server will overwrite x-forwarded-for as it knows it is forwarding from load balancer.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `express`, consider setting `app.set('trust proxy');`

For more information, check the [express manual page on 'Express behing proxies'](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)