# How can I get the clients ip address in an Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to get my clients IP address in an Azure function. How would I do that without using system.web

There are many similar questions but all answers are using system.web ex:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582553/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-azure-functions-c)

It seems a bit overkill to me to bring in all of system.web for such a simple task. Does anybody know a better way?

Thank you

Comment: Are you on full .NET Framework? If so, what's the problem with `System.Web`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're worrying about something that you don't need to.  To read the values, you'll have to load *something*, bet it System.Collections or System.Web or System.Linq or some other combination.

In this case, System.Web is just the way to do it.  That's why it's there.