# Get remote IP address in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

How can I get remote IP address in Azure function?

The `MS_HttpContext` property is not present in the properties of `HttpRequestMessage`, so I cannot use the solution here: [How to get client IP address in Azure Functions C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582553/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-azure-functions-c)

Getting Forwarded For IP address is easy (from the headers, as shown in the link above), but how can I get the remote IP address?

Comment: Is this Functions v2?

Comment: It is .NET Core 2 (functions 2.x)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For .NET Core Functions, we usually use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest`.

When we create a Http trigger template, we can see it.

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
```

Then get remote IP

```
var remoteAddress = req.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```