# How do i get Ip Address from Azure Function Http request with Python

Tags: python, azure, function, http

How i get IP Address from this request HTTP using python? I found some posts using C#, like this:
[Get remote IP address in Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211824/get-remote-ip-address-in-azure-function)

I have this code:

```
import logging
import json
import socket
import getpass
import os
from requests import get
import azure.functions as func
from azure.common.client_factory import    get_client_from_json_dict,get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

Myip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
username = getpass.getuser()

return func.HttpResponse(
         f"List of IPs: {str(Myip)}",
         status_code=200
    )
```

The image shows the result of the local request.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZKm.png

Comment: Here is answer for the same question - [How to get the IP address from incoming request in Azure Functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64472378/how-to-obtain-ip-address-or-hostname-at-runtime-of-requests-sent-to-http-trigg/64474454#64474454)

Answer (score 0):

The result of your request should be saved to a response variable.
Before you read the body of your response, you can use this bit of code to get the IP address.  Say your response variable is called `rsp`

```
print rsp.raw._fp.fp._sock.getpeername()
```

There is a similar question here = [How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library)

More info here, [Python: get remote IP from HTTP request using the requests module](https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2017/06/python-get-remote-ip-from-http-request-using-the-requests-module/)

**Update**
Python3.8 with requests 2.22.0

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.google.com', stream=True)
resp.raw._connection.sock.getsockname()
```

Comment: Hello Troy, thanks for answer.
I have no request, my azure function receive a request HTTP, my code is:

import logging
import json
import socket
from requests import get
import azure.functions as func
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_json_dict,get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

Comment: Hi Troy, i've added my code in post, how do i get this response?
I have the func.HttpResponse in azure functions

Comment: Yes, your Azure function is receiving a request.  Are you looking for that incoming IP address?   Or -now that you have updated your code to make an additional outbound request - are you looking for the IP of `https://api.ipify.org`?  Which one?  Take a look at this question here = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library

Answer (score 0):

You can get the source IP of the incoming request from the x-forwarded-for header in the req object. I use the following code to log it:

```
    if "x-forwarded-for" in req.headers:
        source_ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"].split(':')[0]
        logging.info("Incoming request from IP: " + source_ip)
```