# How to obtain IP address or Hostname, at runtime, of requests sent to HTTP-triggered Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure-functions

How can I get the IP address or Hostname of each client who makes a request to an HTTP-triggered Azure Function?

I need to know **at the time the request is made**, not in logs afterwards.

Comment: That kind of information generally comes in the header parameters of the request, can you show an example of the headers that are arriving in your api?

Comment: I'm using Python within an Azure Function. I can use `req.headers.get()` to get request headers, but from what I see in the actual Request (Postman console), IP/Hostname is not in the request headers. I see an "IP" under `Network/Addresses/Local` in Postman console, but I dont' know if those values come across the wire or are just part of Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you can't find IP/Hostname in the request headers. But I test it in my side, I can get the request IP address by this line:

```
req.headers.get("X-FORWARDED-FOR")
```

When I run the python function on local, it will get `null`. But we can get the IP address after I deploy it to azure.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @HuryShen. How did you know to look for `X-FORWARDED-FOR`? How did you get a list of all available headers?

Comment: Hi @ericOnline We can't get a list of all available headers in this python code. I just search on the internet and found the ip address is stored in the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` of the header.