# Can we seperate one application insight based on request?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Can we  seperate one application insight based on request Means

i dont know how to explain the problem? Because this is not a problem/issue . it's an requirement Provided by client.

Requirement:
I have on function app like ApplicationX .

We can hit our function app from different clients like Applicationy and Applicationz.

When we are creating a funtion app at the same time we can enable application insight for respective function app.

but when we are hitting function app from Application y and Application z the respetive function app application insights are maintaining traces of these applications mixedly.

But i wanted to seperate these traces in one appicationnsight based on application .
I hope u people understand what i want to explain.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Regarding "separate these traces" based on client y and z, does it mean filter the trace logs based on client y and z?

Comment: @Ivan Yang yes 
When we want see these traces in azure application insights it creates a confusion 
to give clearness we want make seperate these traces.
I hope u understand

Comment: I'm not very familiar with azure function. But if you just want to filter these messages by client y and z, you can go to the azure portal -> application insights -> select some traces logs, to see if there are some properties which can be used to identify client y and z.

Comment: @Ivan Yang Already i have tried with azure portal i could not find any thing

Comment: Do you mind post screenshots of the traces' property?

Comment: please find the above image I guess it will be usefull to u

Comment: do you check the property "Cloud role instance" ? are they same when you hit from client y and z?

Comment: @Ivan Yang  I thought that is not realated to this one

Answer (score 0):

You would have below options if "Cloud role instance" is not helping -

1. You can capture the client IP which is invoking your function app and store it in Application Insights and see if that helps you segregate the Application Y and Z in your case.
2. Write custom telemetry with in the function app to read the client y/z name and send it to Application Insights for you to filter.

Related thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582553/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-azure-functions-c).

Hope the above information helps.