# HttpTriggered Azure Function calling IP

Tags: azure-functions

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to get the IP address from where the Azure Function was triggered, when called by a webhook/httptrigger.

I've only looked at PowerShell, since that's what I know, but so far I've found nothing when debugging.

/Per

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client IP address in Azure Functions C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582553/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-azure-functions-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For v2 Function we use `HttpRequest`, so when we use HTTP trigger function, we could use

```
req.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
```

Then you will be able to see the client remote ip.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to see that in PowerShell.

Comment: @Per Juborg, you are using powershell function?

Comment: Yes, but it appears that you don't get a "proper" header when you debug locally in VS Code.

Comment: In a PowerShell Azure function it would look like this  
`$request.Headers."x-forwarded-for".Split(":")[0]`

Comment: Ye I got this from this [issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/213#issuecomment-501745985), but when test local it won't work.