# I want to get IP addresses of users who enter my site with Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
        var webClient = new WebClient();

        var ipAddress = webClient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
        ipAddress = (new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b")).Match(ipAddress).Value;
```

// gives my site IP address

Comment: To what purpose? Most of the time you cannot do anything useful with the user's IP address.

Comment: It will be necessary because I get health data

Comment: You can find the IP using the solution in this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host>

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`

It tells you about requester's host address and port number. Access this object inside your controller. It's usaually available in the form of `HttpContext.Request.Host`

Comment: var ipAddress = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value.ToString(); 
I used it like this but I get "localhost" value

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/getting-host-information-from-current-the-url-in-asp-net-core-31 
I looked, you can see it here

Comment: the user IP address I want