# How do i monitor when and where an image from my server is loaded?

Tags: javascript, image, ip, server-side-scripting, spying

Almost all of us have heard of services like [spypig](http://spypig.com) . I was wondering how do they track client's IP when an image from their server get loaded. To do the same I made an aspx page with `Response.ContentType = "image/png"` but for this my link goes as

www.something.com/imagePage.aspx?id=rndmval

Is there any method by which whenever an image from my server say "mysite.com/images/me.gif" gets loaded on a system i get notified with the ip of that system?
Its similar to monitoring an image. I like the way spypig works, it can monitor an image whenever it gets loaded on any browser. Does anybody know how do they do that???

Comment: Um, `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")`?

Comment: yep.. just figured out from the docs :)

Comment: not the page Ian. I wanna track a single image. A jpg image that gets loaded on any email or webpage and returns me the client's details onLoad.

Comment: @Amit you have to have the image stored on you server in order to track the request; there's no such way as "magic" images that run some code, or so..

Comment: (a part of course from some overflow vulnerabilities that have come up in the past, but I wouldn't use them to provide a service.. :P)

Comment: @redShadow: I have seen some php vulnerabilities in which they tried hiding scripts in a gif image. I tried that too. I concatenated script.js with image.jpg and img.jpg as resultant file. Image loads fine but it never executes the script. Have a look at spypig I wanna know how did they do it

Comment: ...such vulnerabilities are ways to execute code *on the server side*, not *on the client side*.. anyways, you cannot rely on such things, as they might (and should!) get fixed one day..

Comment: @redShadow: word... but does this mean that we cant monitor a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the request, extract the IP address of the client from the request (not sure how to do that in ASP, but there certainly is a way to do that) and store it in a database / send an e-mail / whatever..

No need to set `Content-type` to `image/png`, it's just a nicer way to tell the browser, who is expecting an image, "here it is your image", but unless you return an actual 1x1 PNG image, it doesn't make much sense.

### Update

The IP address should be contained in:

```
Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")
```

If you want a "clean" url, such as `http://example.com/path/to/image.gif`, you have to do something webserver-side; one common hack used in PHP is to make the web server "rewrite" a request to `/path/to/non-existent/file` to something like `/path/to/my/script.php?path=/path/to/non-existent/file`, not sure how to do that with ASP/IIS though...

### Update: How does spypig work

They give you an "image to be put in emails", that is, an `<img>` tag with a `src=""` pointing to some page on their server, containing a unique identifier in its name, for example:

```
http://example.com/track-user.asp?id=ABCD12345678
```

Once the user opens the email containing the image (beware that most email programs require the user to click "load external content" before images are actually loaded -- that is, an anti-tracking measure), a request is sent to the server which stores somewhere a record containing the id, date, ip address and any other interesting information.

Knowing who you sent a certain id to, you can track which is the e-mail that got opened.

(one common trick to get the user click on "load external images", is to send an e-mail that heavily require images to display properly, so the user is encouraged to load them -- and get tracked).

Comment: @redshow: the aspx page works fine and I have returned an image too. But i dont want to use an aspx or any page. I want to let anyone copy an image from my site and simply paste it on an email or any web document. Whenever this image gets loaded by anyone I should get client's details. Its similar to what google analytics does but its with an image not with a webpage.

Comment: You don't copy an image, you copy a HTML `<img>` tag with the `src` attribute set to your ASP page. The page then logs client info and returns a 1x1px image just so that something is returned.

Comment: @IanKuca i agree. but what if i want to write <img src="site.com/some.JPG"> instead of some.ASPX?

Comment: I have never worked with IIS/ASP but there is surely a similar rewrite engine to mod_rewrite for Apache. You need to map the image path to your ASP script. For Apache+PHP: `RewriteRule /image.jpg /script.php`

Answer (score 0):

Looking quickly at this spypig.com it seems that when you create an image it's given a unique ID. This ID is then stored in the database and when someone later enters this image, the system can match this unique ID with e-mail address that has to be notified.

Tracking IPs is actually much simpler. HTTP works on top of TCP/IP so you always know what is the address of the client (it might be a firewall/NAT/spoofed address though).

In ASP this might be useful: [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350) but virtually any HTTP server-side technology will give you access to this information. Look how much my web browser sends when loading an image (any e-mail client will provide similar information):

```
GET /rndmVal/img.gif HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; pl) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.64
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The IP address of client computer can be obtained from TCP/IP connection.

Comment: @Tomsaz: that was a helping reply but i still cant understand how does merely copying <img src="spypig.com/rndmVal/img.gif"> to an email returns the client's detail. I mean we are loading an image not a script. There must be a monitoring mechanism thats tracking the image load....

Comment: @Amit: I haven't used that service (what do you mean by "client's details"?) but when e-mail client opens "spypig.com/rndmVal/img.gif" the spypig.com server can retrieve your e-mail address and subject that you provided when generating the image by fetching it from database using `rndmVal` key.

Comment: @Tomsaz: the way it works is the same. rndmVal is my unique identifier in their db. The image when loaded gives clients IP. when someone opens an email i get notified with the IP os and browser of receiver. I can do it with an aspx page. What I am interested in is that image. The image gives the ip to spypig server which then mails it to me. I just wanna know 'how?' How does image load returns client's IP

Comment: @Amit: see my update. Any e-mail client or web browser will provide plenty of information when accessing this embedded image. Web server/aspx page is free to access and parse them