# How to get IP address of the Client accessing my page where My web page or WebApp is hosted at some remote server

Tags: c#

How to get IP address or machine name of the user accessing my page's URL? I want to restrict the users who access my page using either IP address or machine name. I am going to host my web application at a remote server. Please help me out in solving this.

Comment: Answers already provided, but remember this will only work for static IPs.  Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: @VegetarianVulture: Please stop adding `Any help will be appreciated` to other people's posts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article at W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

you can try:

```
Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")
```