# How to obtain local ip address

Tags: c#, wcf

I've managed to get clients' ip addresses from my server using codes below

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string ipaddress = endpoint.Address;
```

However, if clients are under the same network, all the ip addresses are public ip address of the network.

Is there a way to get local ip addresses of each client if they are under the same AP?
or just simply, is there a easier way to distinguish client from one another?

Comment: afaik you can't figure the private IP of a host unless you explicitly ask for it

Comment: did you read through this:  <http://keyvan.io/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
HttpRequest currentRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
string ipAddress = currentRequest.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

if (ipAddress == null || ipAddress.ToLower() == "unknown")
    ipAddress = currentRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

return ipAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it doesn't help. ipAddress returns public ip address instead of local ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Because of network address translation it is not always possible to identify clients by unique client addresses see **[How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try webrtc's in built feature to connect to STUN server https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/