# Getting IPv4 address of server, not machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address

I have written the following code to get the IPv4 address of my machine. When we deploy this code on the server, this code gives me the IP address of the server, but not the machines IP on which application running?

```
public string getIpAddress()
{
    try
    {
        string myHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        string myIP = null;

        for (int i = 0; i <= System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[i].IsIPv6LinkLocal == false)
            {
                myIP = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[i].ToString();
            }
        }
        return myIP;            
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question, anyway?

Comment: Hi  Joker_vD, question is, when I deploy this code on server, and access the application through any machine I get IPv4 address of server not that local machine IP

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior as this code is running on the server side.

However, if you want to get the client IP address, you can still do it by using the Request object. (See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) for more details or check on google for examples)

Comment: Hi, I have checked with Request.UserHostAddress; but every time it gives me this 127.0.0.1.

Comment: UserHostAddress will captures the IP of the proxy server or router.  See SO post.

Comment: @user3437960 Are you making running a web browser on the server?

Comment: No  Joker_vD, i am not running a web browser on server, I am running browser on my local machine

Comment: What is the url displayed in your browser address bar?