# Get the MAC address and IP Address of a client vists my site

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm using ASP.NET webforms, and would like to get the ip and MAC address of a
 client visiting my site.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Why do you need the MAC address?

Comment: To store in the DB so i can take care that no double vote will be registered.

Comment: @AdamB: Storing IP addresses will not help you do that.  Individuals can have many IPs, and entire countries can share an IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP address from `Request.UserHostAddress`.

You cannot get the MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

You can get IP address using Request.UserHostAddress or Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]. If client is behind the proxy server then you can try to obtain his IP using ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) for more details.

You can't get the MAC addresses unless your clients are on the same physical subnet as the server. To get MAC address within intranet

```
//get all nics
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
//display the physical address of the first nic in the array,
//which should correspond to our mac address
Label1.Text = nics[0].GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
```

or read more [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1770692.aspx?Find%20Visitors%20IP%20and%20MAC%20address).