# Make a page to be accessible only from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2012

I have some pages that are executed by scheduled tasks regularly on the server. 
How can I make these pages to only be accessible from the server? 
What I want is that if the page url is used from anywhere other than the server itself it should return an empty page.

By the way, I don't want to compare `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` with a hard coded IP address

Comment: Hey dude, why did you delete your last question on the functions....it was valid and it was going to be reopened.... Guess you did not want a solution.

Comment: @epascarello well, I'm trying to solve a problem but everybody was closing downvoting the question. as this fiddle worked: https://jsfiddle.net/u0bprym2/ . I think there is another problem with my code

Comment: Do something like this instead: https://jsfiddle.net/rhL7b9fq/1/

Comment: @epascarello sorry for answering later, my internet connection seems to have a problem. well I can not do as you said because as I told each function is in a separate page and I just in my master page (that is common for all pages) I try to call all the functions that are valid in the current page

Comment: @epascarello I found the problem and undeleted the question and added the answer as as a comment. I undeleted the question because I think this is an error that other people would have, so I want to add the answer for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit after the original question was edited:

Create a second web app on a port that's not open.

---

Original answer:

Looks for the IP from where the request comes. If it is different from the server's IP, reject the call.

Here's how you can get the IP [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)

Comment: actually it seems very cool, let me test this closed port thing ;)

Comment: but the application uses same ports as the website. there is no option to change the port

Comment: Make a second app that runs on a different port

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with IIS Access Control.  There is a link in the following link that goes into more detail.

https://serverfault.com/questions/605398/iis-access-control-by-ip-address-for-specific-files-and-folders

Comment: As I said in the question I don't want to hard code the ip addresses

Comment: I agree, it is just another option besides what was already posted, but this also wouldn't be related to Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].  actually little to none programming if at all.