# GET IP Address of Client computer Not the server IP (accessing thru IP Address pf the server)

Tags: c#, ip-address

I need to get the IP address of the client's computer not the server IP. using C#

I made research already and nothing provided the right answer. 
I tried

```
string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    string clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();

HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

none of these worked for me.

I also tried javascript, putting the IP Address in the control and is workingfine. However,  the control valu is not being captured when executed on Page Load event.

Comment: Search is best answer, sometimes ^_^ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net

Comment: Yep. I have for four hors. All of them says the same things. Didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried this 

`String strHostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();

IPAddress =System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();`
but it gets the network's ip