# How can I get a client's local IP address, like 192.168.0.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have already tried all solutions in Stack Overflow question *[How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350)*. It gives me the server's IP address, not the client's LAN IP address.

I need to get client's local IP address, and it must be seen as 192.168.2.1, but I always get the server's IP address instead of it.

Here is my code:

```
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

There is a website doing this, http://net.ipcalf.com/.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: no idea, but you can look at their soruce code for the answer, well assuming it's not a server side thing (which I seriously doubt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)

Comment: they're using an `RTCPeerConnection`.  You can literally copy the HTML and script on that page into a text document and get the same results in Chrome and Firefox.  They are doing it clientside

Comment: You can't get the local client address any other place than at the client. It's not sent along in the request.

Comment: As far as I know, the only thing that worked for me was using ActiveX with Internet Explorer, but that makes the web site very restrictive ;) If that is no problem check: http://codingresource.blogspot.nl/2010/02/get-client-mac-address-ip-address-using.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

You want the *remote* address, not the local address

`context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`

Answer (score -2):

Your code grabs the server IP address, not the client's. Try the following below:

This code was copied from Stack Overflow question *[How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350)*.

```
protected string GetIPAddress()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Comment: Then you should have marked this question as a duplicate

Comment: I have flagged it but in the meantime i also provided an answer.

Comment: this topic is not duplicate because the quuestion you mentioned is about get users wan ip adress like 86.123.127.8 but what am i asking is how can you get user's local ip adress like 192.168.2.1 i wish you read a litte more about the question before judging.