# IP Address always is the same for all users

Tags: asp.net

Before anything I know this question is duplicated but let me tell about my prob

As [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) demonstrated the `Request.UserHostAddress` only captures the IP address of the proxy server or router
for this reason I have used this code to return users IP Address :

```
  string ip = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].Split(',')[0];
```

but it always return `172.30.1.1` when I connect with my PC,
in the other side my Phone is connected to Telecommunication 3G network
when I connected by phone that returns `172.30.1.1` again.
I also use this code:

```
  public static string GetIP4Address()
    {
        string IP4Address = String.Empty;

        foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
            {
                IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (IP4Address != String.Empty)
        {
            return IP4Address;
        }
        foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
        {
            if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
            {
                IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return IP4Address;
    }
```

but results are same.

so How can I return the real IP address of users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated the answer if you would like to take a look. Earlier, I was tired and misunderstood your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misunderstood the question previously.

This is indeed an incorrect lookup and why it is returning the proxy/router ip addresses `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")` is what sites like rapidshare use to limit downloads as a group, and not really useful.

What you want to be doing is comparing the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` variable against it, to check that there isn’t a non-transparent proxy in the way.

**Like so:**

```
' Look for a proxy address first
Dim _ip As String = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")

' If there is no proxy, get the standard remote address
If (_ip = "" Or _ip.ToLower = "unknown") Then _
    _ip = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

**Some more samples:**

**C#**

```
// Look for a proxy address first
    String _ip = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

// If there is no proxy, get the standard remote address
If (_ip == "" || _ip.ToLower == "unknown")
    _ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

**ASP/VBScript**

```
ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
if ipaddress = "" then
   ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
end if
```

Comment: In ASP.Net there is no `MessabeBox` class!.

Comment: It is always return `192.168.4.35 (Internet)` whether internet or local.

Comment: I don't want  all the IP (v4, not v6) addresses of the local computer !

Comment: @Aria Sorry misunderstood, it is really late here and I am tired, please see edit.

Comment: You are welcome, but please pay attention your code looks exactly mine  that I mentioned at the beginning of the question, please take a deep look at `ip` variable you see how I retrieve IP address, that is do what your C# code do !!!!

Comment: @Aria did  you not even attempt to run it?

Comment: Yes I did, I think the problem may be something else, it is always return same IP.