# How to pass IP value in code behind file?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

When window is loading IP will generate I want to call the IP in `Code Behind page load`

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=DisplayIP";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        };
        function DisplayIP(response) {
            document.getElementById("<%=ipaddress.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " + response.ip;
        }
</script>
```

Label

```
<span id = "ipaddress" runat="server"></span>
```

Code behind file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MyIP = ipaddress.InnerText;
    url = "http://ip-api.com/xml/" + MyIP + "";
}
```

[Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weq2J.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `ipaddress` does not contain the expected value is because the `Page_Load` event occurs before the execution of Javascript. You could try to use the `TextChanged` event of your textbox instead.

Alternatively, you could obtain the client's IP address directly in the code-behind, without using javascript ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)).

Here is one of the suggested solutions (taken from the link above):

```
protected string GetIPAddress()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; 
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```