# how to get local IP (not Remote or Public IP) in internet explorer using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, ip

For other browser like Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc. work fine using java script like: [localIP](http://net.ipcalf.com/)

But this method is not working in internet explorer

Comment: Send a get to an asp.net server and respond with the ip : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net
Not realy sure what you need this on the client side for, to identify the user it would be better to use an cookie, session or something the like.

Comment: I  can easily get Public IP but I need private IP to identify PC. Basically I want to give one user & one PC access to my asp.net application.
concept something like user can login form multiple browser of some PC but S/He can't login to our PC browser at same time.