# Getting IP Address of user browsing the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

I am trying to get the IP address of the user who is browsing the website, might be through mobile phones or PC. I have tried using a set of code, but what I get back is `::1`, may I know if this is wrong or it's meant to be like that?

```
private string GetUser_IP()
{
    string VisitorsIPAddr = string.Empty;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
    {
        VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
    {
        VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    ipAddress = VisitorsIPAddr;    
    return ipAddress;
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: `::1` is ipv6 localhost, i.e its you - this is expected when you access the site locally.

Comment: @AlexK. so would it be safe to say that if it's not accessed locally, the web will be able to obtain the user's IP?

Comment: `::1` is the ipv6 equivalent to `127.0.0.1`, it means it is your own machine

Comment: I would go https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.110).aspx because not all clients are behind a load balancer

Comment: Yes, see this: [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) - note that forwarded-for can contain multiple addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::1` and `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are same, they means **THIS** computer. You are connected to your application on same machine, where you have an application. Try to deploy application to some server.

Remember to make sure if you are getting a public or [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) **IP address**.

Comment: How am I able to identify which am I obtaining? Public or private IP..?

Comment: private ip range are: 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255 , 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 , 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 . Check post wiki link :)