# How do I get public and private IP of computer where ASP.NET application open

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip, ipv4

```
  public string GetIPAddress()
  {        
    try
    {
        return  Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
 }
```

My .Net Application run on this public IP `200.191.124.500`  and i am trying to access public IP using above function but it is given me public IP of my server.

How do I get **public and private IP** of computer where **ASP.NET** application open?

it should be match with **https://www.whatismyip.com/**

Comment: You question is unclear. Where is the code you posted running? Are you asking how to obtain the client/browser IP from your server? If so, and you're getting "the ip of your server" then it's likely your server is behind a load balancer. You should ask your provider how to _properly_ obtain the _original/originating client ip_ - usually sent in  `http header`.

Comment: @EdSF  yes ,we required client public IP from myserver . I want know which network access my page

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)